# Truth assessment chain method with reversal method

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-chaining

I would like to achieve a query like object in python that in the background asseses validity with a method chaining design as so:

```
c = Test(a=True, b=False)
c.a.is_not(b).validity()
```

or I can do this

```
c.is_not(a).b.validity()
```

or this

```
c.is_not(a).is_not(b).validity()
```

or like this

```
c.is_not(a).is_not(b).validity()
```

The challenge I am facing is adding a reversal query like method that can accept a property method and return the truth of reversal.
This is my attempt. However I realized this is not a good approach as the validity will be changed twice in case of calling the `is_not()`:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._validity = True

    @property 
    def a(self):
        self._validity = self._validity == self._a
        return self

    @property 
    def b(self):
        self._validity = self._validity == self._b
        return self

    def is_not(self, truth):
        truth = not(truth)
        self._validity = self._validity == truth
        return self

    def validity(self):
        return self._validity
```

Comment: This looks interesting but I don't quite understand the question. `_validity` is updated only once, although `truth` is updated as well. It seems to work. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in your first snippet ?

Comment: @BobZimmermann, what I want is that when I add a is_not, the truth of the function will be evaluated in reverse, false becomes true and the other way around

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers a, and b are just variables that I would like to transfer as properties

Comment: @callmeGuy I mean: what are the actual values you used for `a` and `b` in this snippet ? If we don't know we can't make sense of your snippet, nor try it etc - cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, they are just boolen values

Comment: Having a method that both mutates its object *and* returns a value is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid changing the state of `Test` by constructing a new object to return. Here is a concise version, but it does not necessarily scale well:

```
    @classmethod
    def is_not(cls, truth):
        test = cls(not self.a, not self.b)
        test._validity = not(truth)
        return test
```

This also has the effect that a double negative would become a positive, which may not be what you want.

This is reminiscent of the Monad pattern. One possible way to implement this would be with the `State` monad from [`oslash`](https://github.com/dbrattli/OSlash):

```
import oslash 

class TestMonadic:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def is_not(self, truth: bool) -> oslash.State:
        return lambda validity: oslash.State(lambda _: (truth != validity, self))

    def validity(self, state: oslash.State):
        return state.run(self)[0]
```

The syntax becomes a bit cumbersome in python because it was not designed for this. It might make more sense to place `is_not` and `validity` outside of the class, but owing to their rather general names, it is helpful to bind them to the class. (In Haskell, the function name is not as important because the function type signature would trigger dispatch).

Here is how your calculations would look in this framework:

```
>>> t = TestMonadic(a=True, b=False)
>>> t.validity(State.get() | t.is_not(t.b))
True
>>> t.validity(State.get() | t.is_not(t.a) | t.is_not(t.b))
True
>>> t.validity(State.get() | t.is_not(t.b))
False
```

`oslash` is missing `evalState` which is what `validity()` is partly doing.